# React useEffect to run on both component mounting and dependency change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to know how to run the useEffect side effect in both component mounting and a dependent value change. Currently I'm using two useEffects to achieve this like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const getUsers = async () => {
        try {
            const userResponse = await api.get('/users');
            if (isMounted) { setUsers(userResponse.data); }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    getUsers();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const getUsers = async () => {
        try {
            const userResponse = await api.get('/users');
            if (isMounted) { setUsers(userResponse.data); }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    getUsers();
}, [netInfo]);
```

Is there anyway to achieve this using one useEffect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second one (with the dependency) gets called both on component mount and when the dependency changes.

Comment: Yeah, @Kraylog is correct. `useEffect` triggers on mount every single time and again depending on its dependencies. Is there an error that possibly happens when you only use the 2nd `useEffect`. It might help if you post more of your code.

Comment: there was no error. *netInfo* is a value that's coming from props. I thought maybe that will not let the 2nd useEffect run

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Runs when the component is mounted for the first time and on every re-render

```
useEffect(() => {})
```

Runs when the component is mounted for the first time alone

```
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

Runs when the component is mounted for the first time and whenever the someDependency's value changes .

```
useEffect(() => {}, [someDependency])
```

You can remove the first `useEffect` .